# PDO charset from iso-8859-2 to UTF8

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, pdo

I have a field in MySQL DB:

```
description     text    utf8_general_ci
```

I use CURL to scrap website with iso-8859-2 and try to insert values to utf8_general_ci field. Everyting is okay, but I lose characters ie. ęąśćż etc. Can you guys help me?

I connect to DB via PDO:

```
 $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xx;charset=utf8', 'xxx', 'xxx');
 $pdo -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

than I prepare my query:

```
 $stmt1 = $pdo -> prepare('INSERT INTO `jos_djcf_items1` (`cat_id`, `user_id`, `name`, `description`, `intro_desc`, `date_start`, `display`, `published`, `contact`)    VALUES(
                                :cat_id,
                                :user_id,
                                :name,
                                :description,
                                :intro_desc,
                                :date_start,
                                :display,
                                :published,
                                :contact)'); // 1
```

And I check charset:

```
$oferta[$j][0]= iconv("iso-8859-2","UTF-8",$nazwa);
$ary[] = "UTF-8";
$ary[] = "iso-8859-2";
$ary[] = "EUC-JP";
echo mb_detect_encoding($oferta[$j][0], $ary);
// it returns: UTF-8
$oferta[$j][1]=iconv("iso-8859-2","UTF-8",$krotkiOpis);
$oferta[$j][2]=iconv("iso-8859-2","UTF-8",$opis);
$oferta[$j][3]=iconv("iso-8859-2","UTF-8",$kontakt);
$oferta[$j][4]=rand(3,40);
```

than I bind Values and execute query

```
$count += $stmt1 -> execute();
```

Comment: What's your PHP version? Passing `charset` in the DSN isn't supported until 5.3.6

Comment: My PHP version was below 5.3.6. Thank you Jack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prior to PHP 5.3.6, this is how you should set the connection character set:

```
$options = array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
);

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xx', 'xxx', 'xxx', $options);
```

Note that the encoding must be ASCII compatible.